# LinearLayout hidden by MapView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout in which is a MapView. I'm trying now to set a LinearLayout above this MapView, so I mean on the Top, but the MapView shall fill the whole screen.

The problem is now that the MapView is shown, but the **LinearLayout** with the id "map_zoomcontrols" is **hidden**.

Is there a way to bring the LinearLayout to the front?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map_zoomcontrols"         
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="150dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"> 
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/map_zoom_out"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="Out"
    android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#fff"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/map_zoom_in"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="In"
    android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_selector"
    />

</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="..."/>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_ll"     
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_bottom"
            android:layout_width ="120dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Bottom"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the XML, or code for this.

Comment: Ok, I posted the code now. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `LinearLayout` **after** the `MapView` control in the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="..."/>


      <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map_zoomcontrols"         
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="150dp" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"> 
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/map_zoom_out"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Out"
        android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="#fff"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/map_zoom_in"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="In"
        android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape_selector"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_ll"     
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_bottom"
            android:layout_width ="120dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Bottom"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oh, that works, great!! So the MapView hides all elements defined before..ok. Thanks!

Comment: @robinson1 `RelativeLayout` allows the children to stay on top of each other so because you defined the `MapView` with `fill_parent` it will cover any element defined before in the layout.